# How to avoid glare in macro photography?

Tags: lighting, macro, glare

I am attempting to take pictures of antique pocket watches, when I use my flash, even with a diffuser or farther away, I get glare from the curved elements within the watch.  Are there any sites with tips and tricks to try to avoid this?

Comment: Could you please post an example image to make it easier to diagnose the problem you are having with the lighting?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For macro of reflecting things you need a as big as possible lightsource.
Best would be a macro tent, but you can improvise with a few pieces of paper and light sources. Just cut one piece of paper in half, form a ring from the two pieces, put them on some other papers and put light sources outside the paper:

[image: Cheap light tent]

If the stuff is really reflective, put another piece of paper on top and leave just a small opening to take the photo through:

[image]

(My own pictures, taken from my own [blog entry about macro tents](http://www.radeldudel.de/blog/0807/Makrostudio.html))

[Update] Strobist just posted a [nice explanation for a small macro tent](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2010/09/meet-new-neighbors.html), too.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried a polarising filter? They reduce glare and reflections generally, so it might well help in your case.